# Is this Scala/Akka idiomatic and correct for Akka 2.1?

Tags: scala, akka

I'm wondering if there is anything i'm overlooking in the code below. I've taken the [Pi calculation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/intro/getting-started-first-scala.html#Bootstrap_the_calculation) example, simplified it and converted it to Akka 2.1.

More specifically, i use the ask pattern to replace the Listener actor.

So is this

1. A proper and valid conversion?
2. A reasonable approach?
3. And is there a better approach to waiting for a result from an optionally distributed parallel reduction of a collection? In other words, is this an Akka equivalent of `collection.par.map(work).par.reduce(result)` or is there a better way?

```
object Work extends App {
  // This is just some collection of data to process (possibly remotely).
  val collection = 1 to 10000
  val start = System.currentTimeMillis
  val system = ActorSystem(f"Work${start}%08x${hashCode}%04x")
  // The collection is converted into a stream since it could
  // potentially be huge.
  val master = system.actorOf(Props(new Master(collection.toStream)), name = "master")

  // This replaces what the Listener was doing, i think.
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(12.seconds)
  val result = Await.result(master ? Run, timeout.duration)
  println(s"\n${result}")
  system.shutdown()

  sealed trait WorkMessage
  case object Run extends WorkMessage
  case class Work(start: Int) extends WorkMessage
  case class Result(value: Double) extends WorkMessage

  sealed trait ControlMessage
  case class Complete(elapsed:Long) extends ControlMessage

  class Worker extends Actor {
    def doWork(element: Int): Double = {
      print(s" ${element}")
      return element.toDouble
    }
    def receive = {
      case Work(element) ⇒
        sender ! Result(doWork(element))
    }
  }

  class Master(work: Seq[Int]) extends Actor {
    val nrOfCPUs = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    val nrOfWorkers = nrOfCPUs * 4
    val workSize = work.size
    var nrOfResults: Int = _
    val workerRouter = context.actorOf(
      Props[Worker].withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(nrOfWorkers)), name = "workerRouter")

    var done: ActorRef = _
    def receive = {
      case Run ⇒
        // Save the sender for responding to the ask once all the work is processed.
        done = sender
        work.foreach(element ⇒ workerRouter ! Work(element))
      case Result(value) ⇒
        nrOfResults += 1
        if (nrOfResults >= workSize) {
          done ! Complete(System.currentTimeMillis - start)
          context.stop(self)
        }
    }

  }

}
```

Here's [a gist](https://gist.github.com/nicerobot/4751388) with the full code and a build.sbt to try:

```bsh
curl -ks https://gist.github.com/nicerobot/4751388/raw/run.sh | sh
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an akka expert but I did used akka in a project so these are just some of my observations:

1. `result` is blocking.

   ```
   val result = Await.result(master ? Run, timeout.duration)
   ```

   On case the master takes longer due to load or whatever, the pending result will
   exceed the timeout. Try async ask directly.

   ```
   val result ask(actor, msg).mapTo[String]
   ```
2. In order to remain async you may carry on with an onComplete as
   Future callback:

   ```
   result onComplete {
       case Success(result) => doSomethingOnSuccess(result)
       case Failure(failure) => doSomethingOnFailure(failure)
   }
   ```

   In this case no operation ever blocks the running thread. Read the [Akka docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/futures.html) for more details

> And is there a better approach to waiting for a result from an
>   optionally distributed parallel reduction of a collection? In other
>   words, is this an Akka equivalent of
>   collection.par.map(work).par.reduce(result) or is there a better way?

Operating on distributed data-sets is much better done on an in-memory data processing engine. Using the distributed word count as example, in [Spark](https://spark.incubator.apache.org/) you do:

```
   file.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
    .map(word => (word, 1))
    .reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

Actors are made for message processing such as Twitter or WhatsApp but for  computing tasks that must be fast, you use either MapReduce (Hadoop) for offline crunching of Spark/Storm for real-time processing.  Hope that answers your question.